# How to disable "Resolve pasted references"?

Tags: android, android-studio

"Resolve pasted references" takes forever and freezes UI. How can I disable this? I want Android Studio to be like regular editor like Notepad++. Or please advice what else can I do. It's big time waster for me. Already waiting 20 mins. Even don't know if I have to wait or restart. I pasted about 1000 lines but I think it's still too long time anyways. I'd let to "Resolve pasted references" but not freeze UI.

Comment: I have this problem when pasting certain objects into any class in the 'test' package.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>